# Problem with Quicktime interop for 64bit

Tags: c#, 64-bit, quicktime

I want to build an application using Quicktime ActiveX interop that could run on a 64bit windows seven OS.
My problem is that the 3 dll : AxInterop.QTOControlLib.dll, Interop.QTOControlLib.dll, Interop.QTOLibrary.dll seems not to be compatible with 64bit OS => It leads to a crash as soon as the application is started.
How can I pass through this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must build your program as a x86 program. You can set this at the project properties.